# Fetching data from on chain account Typescript

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

I have been trying to figure out a way to fetch the data from the https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/sysvars
Solana clock pubKey:" SysvarC1ock11111111111111111111111111111111 " with the Typescript SDK
but i cant figure out a way to how to decode the buffer that is recieved when using the function onAccountUpdate()
Does anyone have any idea how to proceed with this? Thanks## Heading ##

Comment: Do you have non-functioning code you can post with your question so we can help you with it?